# Setup Mac OS JAVA_HOME

Tags: macos, mac, java, path, osx-el-capitan

I have fresh installation of OS X El Captain version 10.11.5. In my `.bash_profile` I did setup Java home as

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

However if I type `echo $JAVA_HOME` results is empty line. My version of Java is 1.8.0_92

EDIT: At the time of writing I did not included not about using zsh instead of default shell. I did not linked the issue with changed of shell type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### echo `$JAVA_HOME` results in an empty line

> With the Java optional package or Oracle JDK installed,   adding one
>   of the following lines to your `~/.bash_profile` file will set the
>   environment variable accordingly.
>
> ```
>    export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
> ```

Source [Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Yosemite (10.10), Mavericks (10.9), Mountain Lion (10.8) or OSX Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6588410/3536342), answer by [Olivier Refalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258689/olivier-refalo)

Comment: Thanks David, but I just figured out what is the issue. I changed from bash to zsh and declaration has to be in `.zshrc` (I am still looking for way to point to .bash_profile instead of maintaining to path definitions)

Comment: David I am not trying to invalidate your answer. My apology if I gave you that impression. In all fairness I did not realised that these two things are related, therefore I did not included in original question.